# How can I apply drift correction from one dataframe to coordinates in another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

Hello stackoverflow community,

I do have two datasets in a dataframe format. One dataset source is a pointcloud over time, which is represented by coordinates  and extra columns for other features . Per timepoint, which is indicated by the column frame, several points can occur. Therefor frame is not unique.

The dataframe drift, has a correction vector for each frame.

I would like to apply the change in `x, y, z` respectively to the source file.
Below you see a minimal example of how my source and drift file look like and how I would like the corrected cooridinate file to look like.

As an example, for the entries in frame = 3 in source, which there are three entries, for all of them the x coordinate should be changed by -2.

> ```
> `source=pd.DataFrame([(1,1,1,2,'var'),(1,1,3,2,'var'),(2,2,1,2,'var'),(3,1,4,2,'var'),(3,1,2,2,'var'),(3,1,5,2,'var')],columns=['frames','x','y','z','c'])`
>
> `drift=pd.DataFrame([(1,0,0,0),(2,0,1,-1.5),(3,-2,1,2),(4,1,1,2),(5,1,0,0)],columns=   ['frames','x','y','z'])`
> ```

> `corrected=pd.DataFrame([(1,1,1,2,'var'),(1,1,3,2,'var'),(2,2,2,0.5,'var'),(3,-1,5,4,'var'),(3,-1,3,4,'var'),(3,-1,8,4,'var')],columns=['frames','x','y','z','c'])`

The challanges are that I do not program at all (first time that I open a jupyter notebook), and secondly that those datasets are huge (>50000000 entries for source and mostly around unique 1000000 frames.)

I did try naively to set frames as index and just add the entries in a new dataframe source_dc:

> ```
> `source_dc = source.copy()`
> `source_dc['x'] = source['x'] + drift['x']`
> `source_dc['y'] = source['y'] + drift['y']`
> `source_dc['z'] = source['z'] + drift['z']`
> ```

Since the frame entries in "source' are not unique and it takes forever, this is not really an option.

Then I tried to merge them, which works, and then create a new dataframe to add both columns, but that is tooo computational expensive.

> `source = pd.merge( left=source, right=drift, left_on='frame', right_on='frame', how='outer' )`

Is there a way to apply the summation directly and maybe write it row by row into a new file?
I definetly need help...
Thank you!